# Grails Unit Test Service MissingProperty 'log'

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I want to run a unit test for a service. The method I want to test includes a some `log.debug()` statements. While the `log` property is injected at runtime, it does not seem to be injected in tests, so it throws `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class:`

This is my unit test class:

```
@TestFor(ServiceUnderTest)
@Mock([ServiceUnderTest])
class ServiceUnderTestTests {

    def test() {
        def mock = [ mockedProp: [...] ] as ServiceUnderTest
        def info = mock.doOperation()
        assert ....
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding `MockUtils.mockLogging(ServiceUnderTest)` but with no success.

How can I get the log property properly injected in my service class while in unit tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to have the test class annotated with `@Mock([ServiceUnderTest])`. `@TestFor(ServiceUnderTest)` detects its a service class and does all the mocking automatically. It also adds a `service` property to the test class that can be accessed in all the test methods and mocks the `log` property accordingly.

I think the problem why neither mocking nor explicit log mocking with `MockUtils.mockLogging(ServiceUnderTest)` does work in your case is the `as` coercion you are using in your test method code:

```
def mock = [ mockedProp: [...] ] as ServiceUnderTest
```

Groovy internally uses `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to create a proxy descendant class from `ServiceUnderTest`. The proxy class does not see changes done to the `ServiceUnderTest` meta class like the added `log` property.

I would solve this issue by using a  *per-object meta class*. You can mock the property getter (or setter) by altering the `metaClass` of the `service` object. Be aware that meta-class changes are rolled back by Grails in-between execution of test methods:

```
service.metaClass.mockedProp = {-> ... }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Groovy is so powerfull, that it can be hard to use the right way at a specific problem....

Comment: Yes, a lot of stuff happening behind the scenes. And sometimes, like in this example, you need to know about some of those things :-)